# C# LINQ: How to find IList<Peak>.Max?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find the tallest peaks in a given latitude and longiture.
I'm trying to modify [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269000/c-finding-local-maxima-over-a-dynamic-range/5269160#5269160) to work with class Peak but don't understand how to use .Max on `IEnumerable<Peak>` rather than `IEnumerable<double>.`
The compiler, of course, complains

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to
>   operands of type 'double' and 'Peak'

This is my first time using LINQ.
How do I find the Max Elevation in `IEnumerable<Peak> range?`

```
public class Peak
{
    readonly Double latitude;
    public Double Latitude { get { return latitude; } }
    readonly Double longitude;
    public Double Longitude { get { return longitude; } }
    readonly Double elevation;
    public Double Elevation { get { return elevation; } }
    public Peak(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double elevation)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.elevation = elevation;
    }
}
private IList<Peak> FindPeaks(IList<Peak> values, int rangeOfPeaks)
{
    var peaks = new List<Peak>();
    var checksOnEachSide = rangeOfPeaks / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        var current = values[i];
        IEnumerable<Peak> range = values;
        if (i > checksOnEachSide)
            range = range.Skip(i - checksOnEachSide);
        range = range.Take(rangeOfPeaks);
        if (current.Elevation == range.Max())
            peaks.Add(current);
    }
    return peaks;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `Max<Peak>` usage to find the max `Elevation`:

```
if (current.Elevation == range.Max(p => p.Elevation))
    peaks.Add(current);
```

I suggest you to read a little about [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to better understand how this sintax works.

Comment: I'll follow your suggestion now. Thanks.

Comment: Also this thread is very good to understand why lambdas are a powerfull thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this.

Answer (score 5):

Specify the property you want the maximum of:

```
if (current.Elevation == range.Max(p => p.Elevation))..
```