# How to determine trough in time-series data?

Tags: fft, frequency-analysis, time-frequency

I am receiving a stream of time-series data/events from a manufacturing process machine.  I need to be able to calculate the start of a cycle and pinpoint this event based on the trough of the data.  What would be a recommended way to do this?

Thanks

Edit: I've attached an image of the data graph.  Basically I have an ongoing stream of data that I need to be able to effectively identify the troughs in order to establish the start of the next cycle/end of the previous cycle.  The only thing I'm guaranteed not to know is the period of the cycle - it will vary.

The only thing I'm guaranteed to know is the initial datapoint value - which could be anywhere in the cycle.

At the moment - I'm kind of thinking I have to do something with a sliding span of time, keeping tracking of the minimum temp seen so far.

[image]

Comment: What about sharing some data or simulated data and what you have done so far.

Comment: ended with this: [Finding Local Maxima Over a Dynamic Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269000/finding-local-maxima-over-a-dynamic-range) Thanks for the help :)